# Timer stops whenever an error occurred in the subscription

Tags: angular, error-handling, timer, rxjs, observable

I have a service which run a timer in its constructor.
The timer calls an asynchrony function which call an API and should return an Observable.
It is running fine when everything is OK.
I'm trying to implement error handling now, whenevr the API is down.
The problem is that whenever an error occurred, the timer executions stops.

See my code:

```
subscription : Subscription;
constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient)
{
    this.subscription = timer(0, 10000).pipe
    (
        switchMap(() => this.getData();
    }).subscribe();
}


getData(): Observable<someModel>
{
    return this.httpClient.get<someModel>(<url>)
    .pipe(
    tap(response => 
    {
        do something 
    }),
    catchError(error =>
    {
        <doSomeErrorHandling>
        return throwError(error);
    })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observable is closed when an error occurs. So instead of forwarding the error using `throwError` function, you could convert it to a `next` notification using [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) function. If you're worried it might tangle up the actual response handling mechanism, you could using RxJS [`NEVER`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/NEVER) constant to not emit anything from the `catchError` block.

Try the following

```js
import { of, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
getData(): Observable<someModel>{
  return this.httpClient.get<someModel>(<url>).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      do something
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      // <doSomeErrorHandling >
      return of(error); // (or) return NEVER;
    })
  );
}
```

Also try to use `tap` only for side-effects. In your case with only a single `switchMap` you could handle the notifications inside the subscription.

Comment: When I used operator A the solution was destroyed, the second way worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

switchMap emits an error if any of it's inner observables [`this.getData()`, in this case], error. In instead, you likely want to catch errors on the inner observables themselves.

Remember also that a RxJS steams emit one `error` **or** one `complete` emission. Never more and never both. If an error reaches your switchMap, that part of your stream is done for good. You can, instead, use retry to re-create the the stream from scratch.

```js
subscription : Subscription;
constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient){
  this.subscription = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.getData().pipe(
      catchError(err => /*Do something*/)
    )
  ).subscribe();
}
```